# Can I have different host mount in pods from same deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, containers

For logs, I mount a volume from host on to the pod. This is written in the deployment yaml.
But, if my 2 pods run on the same host, there will be conflict as both pods will produce log files with same name.
Can I use some dynamic variables in deployment file so that mount on host is created with different name for different pods?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [subPathExpr](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath-with-expanded-environment-variables) to achieve the uniqueness in the absolute path, this is one of the use case of the this feature. As of now its is alpha in k1.14.

> In this example, a Pod uses subPathExpr to create a directory pod1 within the hostPath volume /var/log/pods, using the pod name from the Downward API. The host directory /var/log/pods/pod1 is mounted at /logs in the container.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container1
    env:
    - name: POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    image: busybox
    command: [ "sh", "-c", "while [ true ]; do echo 'Hello'; sleep 10; done | tee -a /logs/hello.txt" ]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir1
      mountPath: /logs
      subPathExpr: $(POD_NAME)
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: workdir1
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log/pods
```

Comment: Any other way apart from this, this I have already thought off.

Answer (score 0):

look at pod affinity/anti affinity to not to schedule the replica on the same node. that way each replica of a specific deployment gets deployed on separate node. you will not have to bother about same folder being used by multiple pods.

Answer (score 0):

I had to spend hours for this, your solution worked like a charm!
Had tried with, none worked despite being given in multiple documents.
subPathExpr: "$POD_NAME"
subPathExpr: $POD_NAME
subPathExpr: ${POD_NAME}

Finally this worked, subPathExpr: $(POD_NAME)